# figure with subfigures linewidth overlap

Tags: floats, subfloats, changepage

I would like to dsiplay two figures next to each other, but wider than the actual line- or textwidth. I am using the `subfigure` environment to display the figures. This is my code so far:

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{first_file.pdf}
        \vspace{5pt}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{second_file.pdf}
        \vspace{5pt}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{} \label{Gyr}
\end{figure}
```

In this configuration, the figures will be displayed next to each other but too small. If I use `0.5\linewidth` or larger, the figures will be displayed on top of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Red lines indicate text width / margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.475\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.475\linewidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{} \label{Gyr}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{} \label{Gyr}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.1\linewidth}{-0.1\linewidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.475\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.475\linewidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \caption{} \label{Gyr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually my problem is not enlarging a figure (or table) and then trying to fit the result on a page, but rather on a more common one:

How to fit a figure (or more, on a single line) **without altering its natural width(s),** when that width is greater than the allocated text width?

The solution is to use the outer margin (books and reports) or perhaps both the inner and outer margin with the articles. Only if the publisher agrees!

The   `adjustwidth` environment from the package `changepage` allows for the expansion of the margins, locally, to make it possible to insert material wider than the width of the text line, without altering the natural width or the  aspect ratio of the material being inserted.

I use as spare space `\marginparwidth+\marginparsep` or perhaps  going a little further `\marginparwidth+\marginparsep+0.5\oddsidemargin`,

The example shows four 100pt wide squares plus a smaller 40pt wide in a single row.

The original  `\textwidth` is 390pt and the  `\spare` 60.5pt.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % <<<< needed

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{float} %[H]

\usepackage{showframe} % margins
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\begin{document}
\newlength{\spare}
\setlength{\spare}{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep+0.5\oddsidemargin}         

1.  \kant[1]

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{-\spare}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-grid-100x100pt} % a figure 100pt wide
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-grid-100x100pt}   
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-grid-100x100pt} % 40pt wide
\end{adjustwidth}
    \caption{4*100pt + 40pt; textwidth = \the\textwidth; spare = \the\spare}    
\end{figure}    

9.  \kant[9]
    
\end{document}
```

You only need to use the package `subcaption` if you intend to use subcaptions below each figure.

Since you are squeezing things in a tight spot, they do not need to be centered.

[image: B]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustwidth}{0pt}{-\spare}
    \begin{subfigure}{85pt}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{example-grid-100x100pt} % a figure 85pt wide
        \caption{One}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{85pt}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{example-grid-100x100pt} % 
        \caption{Two}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{85pt}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{example-grid-100x100pt} % 
        \caption{Three}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{85pt}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{example-grid-100x100pt} % 
        \caption{Four}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{85pt}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.85]{example-grid-100x100pt} % 
        \caption{Five}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \caption{5*85pt; textwidth = \the\textwidth; spare = \the\spare}    
    \end{figure}
```